# To delete the HashMap data in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, hashmap, jstl

I created a HashMap and sending it to UI for display purpose, but I want to remove some particular object from the map using JSTL tag.

```
<c:forEach items="${BeanHashMap}" var="BeanHashMap">
<c:if test="${HashMapForLoop.containsKey('YearRange')}">
<%-- ${accruedAnticipatedBonusDetailsBeanHashMap.remove('accuredAnticipatedYearRange')} --%>
</c:if>
```

I don't know whether I am doing right or not.

**Note**:- I can iterate and match the content, but again it will be the time consumption issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set the value to null using `<c:set>`

- target - your map object
- property - the key of the object you want to
  remove

Sample:

```
<c:set target="${BeanHashMap}" property="YearRange" value="${null}"/>
```